# why does java generics allow passing boolean value in get for HashMap<Integer,String>

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, autoboxing

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, "aaa");
hashMap.put(2, "baa");
hashMap.put(3, "caa");
System.out.println(hashMap.get(false));
```

Above code compiles and runs fine.. gives output as `null`.

What I am trying to understand is there any autoboxing happening in-between that i seem to miss. Because if generics are applied at compile time, get method shall not allow us to pass a boolean there.

Thanks

Comment: `boolean` is autoboxed to `Boolean`. Your code is `System.out.println(hashMap.get((Boolean) false));`

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch! Boolean being sublcass of Object it works.

Answer (score 3):

The `get` method of HashMap is defined as `public V get(Object arg0) {`.
That means you can put any object as parameter. That method do not use generics, so the Parameter is not checked by the Compiler.

Here you can find the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the mao imnplementation is taking **Object** as parameter, so you basically can pass as param whatever you want...

```
V get(Object key);
```

and the HashMap

```
public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V> e;
    return (e = getNode(hash(key), key)) == null ? null : e.value;
}
```

so if you give another instance as parameter the method will return **null**

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `get` method in `public class HashMap<K,V>` is

```
get(Object key)
```

It isn't generic. So it's not just `boolean`, you can pass any object and it will give some output (or `null` if it doesn't exists).

---

I think you're confusing this signature with

```
get(K key)
```

If it was a signature of this kind, then your operation wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

[`Map.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) isn't a generic method. That way it maintains comparability with pre-generics Java. If it were generic, to maintain compatibility would require dropping the old method (because all types would match `Object` causing ambiguity for the compiler).